# Inverse prediction using drm package in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I've fit a model using a 5 parameter logistic fit using the drm library. I apologize if this is a dumb question; I'm just getting started with r.

If dose in on my x-axis and response is on my y-axis, it is very easy to use this model to predict my response based on a given dose. You can either use the function PR or predict. However, I want to estimate a dose for a given response.  I can't find a function to do this.  For my assay, I fit my data to a standard curve and now I have measured a response from my unknowns. I would like to estimate concentration (dose) based on this response.   I  could fit the data in the opposite direction (flip x and y) but the fit differs slightly and that's not a very conventional strategy. If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate them. thank you

Comment: Removing the statement "I apologize if this is a dumb question" is not a grammar correction. Please don't edit the content of the post - that's not the point of edits.

Answer (score 4):

In case any one comes across this, the easiest way to do this is to use the ED function with the argument type = "absolute".